# Disable touchpad when external mouse is connected

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1903

This may seem a duplicate question, but it isn't. I tried several tutorial to disable the internal touchpad but I neither have the disable option in the defenitions or the touchpad tab in mouse settings or a icon in the taskbar. There is another way to disable the touchpad when I connect an external mouse?
I have the 19.5.35.26 Synaptics version installed.

Comment: Many keyboards have a button for disabling touchpad (on my Lenovo ideapad it's F6)

Comment: You didn’t provide the make and model of your laptop. But, every laptop has a way to disable to touchpad. Simply read the manual.

Comment: I have an HP laptop, and it don't say how to disable the touchpad and I don't have a key to disable the touchpad. I have that disabled in the 1803 windows version, but with the updates the touchpad became active all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I reverted the driver to the version before, version 19.5.10.69, and now I have the ability to disable it when an external mouse is being used.